# Change line color in QQ plot using qqggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, ggpubr

I have used qqggplot from the `ggpubr` package in R, and I would like to modify it so that the reference line is red, not black... Does anyone know how to do that without making everything red? I am not too familiar with the ggplot2 package. Also, I would like the confidence interval to be grey, so the qqnorm from the stats package won't do. I hope someone can help!

I have already tried to set the color to red, but that makes everything red, like the code line below.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggqqplot(residuals, add="qqline", xlab="\n Theoretical quantiles", 
         ylab="Sample quantiles", shape=1, ylim=c(-5,5), col="red")
```

So how do I make a QQ plot where the reference line is red, with grey confidence bands? If someone knows of another function I could use, feel free to suggest it. I have tried `qqPlot` from car and `qqnorm` from extRemes, but I prefer the format from `qqggplot`...

[image]

Comment: Save your plot as `p` and then try `p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- "red"; p`

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

two lines of code without any special packages:

`qqnorm(residuals)`

`qqline(residuals,col="red")`